# Problem reading hex data from image - python automatically converts to a string

Tags: python, string, image, hex

I am reading in an image one byte at a time with with read(1), and appending it to a list. The image data is all hex data. When I print out the list with the `print` function it is in the format `'\xd7'`

```
['\xd7', '\xd7', '\xd7', '\xd7', '\xd7', '\xd7', '\xd7',...]
```

The problem is that now I need to perform some calculations on this hex data, however, it is in string format, and this '\xd' string format isn't supported by any of the int or hex conversion functions in python. They require a `'0xd7'` or just a `'d7'`.

Thanks for the help

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do, but are you aware of the Python Imaging Library? It may be easier than manipulating image data yourself. http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you require `'d7'` or `'0xd7'`, rather than simply `0xd7` (viz, 215), `hex()` or `'%x'` are your friend.

```
>>> ord('\xd7')
215
>>> ord('\xd7') == 215 == 0xd7
True
>>> hex(ord('\xd7'))
'0xd7'
>>> '%x' % ord('\xd7')
'd7'
```

Also as observed in other answers, do make sure you open with the 'b' in the mode, otherwise it can get messed up, thinking it's UTF-8 or something like that, on certain sequences of bytes.

Answer (score 4):

It's interpreting them as characters, so use ord to turn them into numbers. I.e. `ord('\xd7')` gives 215.

Also if you use Windows, or the program might have to run on Windows, make sure that you've got the file open in binary mode: `open("imagefile.png","rb")`. Makes no difference on other operating systems.

Comment: `b` applies on Windows, but not on Linux or Mac.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. All the same, it's good practice to write code that will work the same anywhere.

Comment: @Greg: `b` is not necessary on *x boxes. However you should always use `b` so that your code is portable and the intent is clear anyone reading your code.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this to get them into a numeric array:

```
import array

data = array.array('B') # array of unsigned bytes

with open("test.dat", 'rb') as input:
    data = input.read(100)
    data.fromstring(data)

print data
# array('B', [215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215])
```

Comment: Though for Python 2.6+ using an `array` for byte data is over complicated - just use a bytearray: `b = bytearray(input.read(100))`, nothing to import and you can use plain indexing without `ord`. (Also best to avoid hiding the built in `bytes` type).

Comment: @Scott Griffiths: I initially wrote this using `bytearray`, but noticed they print like strings -- and decided the "complications" were worth it, plus the `array` module has been around for a long, long time so this will work with many more of the older versions of Python [still] out there.

Answer (score 1):

`read()` can take a size value larger than 1: `read(1024)` will read 1K worth of bytes from the stream. That will be a lot faster than reading a byte at a time and appending it to the previous bytes.

What are you trying to do when printing the data? See the byte values, or display the image?

The data isn't in "string format", it's just bytes, but when you print them the print routine will escape non-printing values into something that will mean more to human eyes and brains. If you want to see the values without the escaping you can iterate over the bytes and convert them to their hexadecimal values, or decimal, or binary - whatever works for you and your application. The [string formatting mini-language](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) will be a good starting place.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing image processing, then you probably want to look at numpy.

There are a few packages that will help you read your image into memory too (PIL is mentioned above, another is my own [mahotas](http://scikits.appspot.com/image) or [scikits.image](http://scikits.appspot.com/image)).

If the data is in a file as raw data an you know the dimensions, you can do the following

```
import numpy as np
img = np.empty( (n_rows, n_cols), dtype=np.uint8) # create an empty image
img.data[:] = input_file.read()
```

to get your data into `img`.

An introductory website for image processing in python is http://pythonvision.org.